# How to continuously create file name with special character like () and white space in Linux?

Tags: shell, filenames

I am trying to create a lot of files using `C`. I have done `mkdir -p  directory && touch directory/filename`. When my loop reached a file with a special character in it's name, I get the error

```
syntax error :" unexpected "("
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Why "using c"? You don't seem to use `C`, but the shell (probably `bash`)

Comment: All ready I wrote logic using c .but when program reach that point that time error like this .so can you merge bash script with c ? Can you please evaporate it ?

Comment: My answer below shows how to quote a file name with special characters in `bash`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surround the file path with quotes like this:

```
touch "directory/file"
```

Comment: That doesn't work for file names that contain double quotes or backslashes or `$` or `\``.

Answer (score 2):

You problem seems to be, that you are trying to create your files/directories using something like `system()`.  Use of `system()` is highly discouraged, as it spawns a shell to execute the given command.  This also means, that the spawned shell will evaulate the full command using its own syntax, hence you'll have to escape characters that are treated specially by the shell.

A more robust (and less error-prone) way to create files and directories from C is using the real C functions offered for this task, namely `mkdir()` and `open()`/`creat()`:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int
main(void)
{
  char dir[] = "some(directory)with*special[characters]";
  char file[] = "some(file)with*the[same]characters";
  int fd;

  if (mkdir(dir, 0755) == -1)
    err(EXIT_FAILURE, "creating directory failed");
  if ((fd = open(file, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0644)) == -1)
    err(EXIT_FAILURE, "creating file failed");
  close(fd);

  /* ... */

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to "quote" the filename:

```
touch "directory/file with whitespace (and special characters)"
```

Please read about quoting and special characters in the bash manual.

Comment: That doesn't work for file names that contain double quotes or backslashes or `$` or `\``.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `system()` within `C` to invoke shell commands that take arguments, best is to use the environment to pass those arguments to avoid having to quote them.

With the path of the file (containing any character) stored at `file_path`:

```
if (setenv("FILE", file_path, 1) < 0) {
  perror("setenv");
  exit(1);
}
system("mkdir -p -- \"$(dirname -- \"$FILE\")\" && touch -- \"$FILE\"");
```

That way, you're passing a fixed string to `sh -c` (called by `system()` internally) and don't have to worry with arbitrary  code injection vulnerabilities as long as your shell code is correct (note the quotes and `--` above).

(the above has the usual `sh` command substitution issue whereby all trailing newline characters are stripped, so it would fail on a `file_path` like `foo/bar\n/file`. I'll leave it to you to decide if you want to make the effort to work around that).

If you wanted to pass the file names in the shell code passed to `system()`, do **not** do:

```
sprintf(cmd, "mkdir -p -- \"%s\" && touch -- \"%s\"", dir_path, file_path);
```

as that would still be a command injection vulnerability (for instance with a filename like `$(reboot)` or `";reboot;:"`. Same if you used single quotes instead of double quotes.

You'd need:

```
sprintf(cmd, "mkdir -p -- %s && touch -- %s",
  shquote(dir_path), shquote(file_path));
```

where `shquote()` would be a function (whose implementation is left as an exercise) that replaces every `'` character with `'\''` and encloses the result in single quotes. So for instance returns `'foo'\''bar'` for `foo'bar` (bear in mind that the length of the quoted file can be up to 4 * length + 2, which you'll need to take into account when allocating space for the `cmd` buffer).

That's the safest quoting approaches. Quoting approaches that use double quotes or backslashes all have issues in some locales using exotic charsets that can cause arbitrary code injection vulnerabilities.